# elasticsearch unable to configure remote cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kibana, kubernetes-ingress

I wanted to connect 2 elastic clusters (7.10) with the remote cluster, to see indices on one kibana.
my two clusters are on Kubernetes. first I tried to configure the elastic Ip with endpoint( I use ingress), do you know if this possible I did not succeeded?
After that, I also expose a node port but I still can't connect to remote elastic.(when I did curl on remote elastic cluster it worked **curl 192.88.188.88:3333**

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "connect_transport_exception",
        "reason" : "[]] handshake_timeout[30s]"
          }
```

can you please assist what I did wrong?

```
{
  "persistent": {
    "cluster": {
      "remote": {
        "cluster_one": {
          "seeds": [
            "127.0.0.1:9200"
          ],
          "transport.ping_schedule": "30s"
        },
        "cluster_two": {
          "mode": "sniff",
          "seeds": [
            "192.88.88.88:3333"
          ],
          "transport.compress": true
          }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I think 127.0.0.1:9200 is wrong. set port to 9300 and check again

Comment: and 3333 maybe is wrong. check cluster_two elastic connection port. you should set it to 9301 in your cluster and here.

Comment: I'm connecting to remote elastic search on kuberiq so 9200 is not exposed I have an different port that direct to 9200